# How to get gzip or brotli encoding on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, compression, gzip, brotli

Does Google App Engine allow compression of the results? For example, I have the following curl request:

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/' \
> --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'
```

And the response is not compressed. Compare this with something like:

```
$ curl --location -X GET 'https://google.com' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Or, is there something manual I need to set up? I would think the last resort would be to do the compression in the application endpoints themselves, or is that how it needs to be done?

Comment: What is the HTTP response header **content-type** returned by your code? In order to compress, App Engine requires compatible content such as HTML, CSS,  JavaScript, etc. (text-based data). The curl command can tell you what the response headers are (the -v option).

Comment: @JohnHanley oh thank you for pointing that out! Yes, once I make sure the content-header is set and the content itself is valid it compresses it correctly, in this case using gzip: `$ curl --location --request GET 'https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/html' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -v`

Comment: Post an answer with the change you made. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on John Hanley's suggestion in a comment, there are two parts to this.

1. You have to set the `Accept-Encoding` header in the request.
2. Second, the response itself should have the proper content- or mime-type, such as `text/html` or whatever it needs to be. Often the web server will ignore compression if the mime-type isn't in a certain list.
3. Third, to ensure that the headers in both the requests and responses are correct you can use the `-v` flag in curl.
4. Finally, it seems the content needs to be over a certain size for the web server to bother compressing it. So, for example, if the content-length is 3, it's not going to be compressed, though I'm not sure exactly what this is.

Putting it all together:

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/html' 
        --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
        -v
```

**References:**

- [curl](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html#-v--verbose)
- [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/go111/how-requests-are-handled#response_compression) (a bit buried, under the Go documentation)

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/request-headers?tab=python#request_headers)

> For example, the server may automatically send a gzipped response depending on the value of the Accept-Encoding request header. The application itself does not need to know which content encodings the client can accept.

That gives the impression it should. But the same documentation also says

> In addition, the following headers are removed from incoming requests because they relate to the transfer of the HTTP data between the client and server:
>
> - Accept-Encoding

I tested against our production site and in FireFox, Web Developer Tool shows `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` as a request header and a response header of `content-encoding: gzip`

However, when I tested against local/dev of our site, Web Developer Tool shows `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` as a request header but the response header didn't include `content-encoding: gzip`. In addition, printing the headers in Flask/Python, gave a value of `None` for `Accept-Encoding`

Comment: local/dev: is this with dev_appserver.py? If so, it is expected that transport encoding compression is not the same as the "production" servers